# Galasoft MVVM-Light and treeview events

Tags: wpf, mvvm, treeview, eventtrigger

I try to bring the galasoft mvvm-light framework to work with my wpf treeviev control, but no command method will be called in corresponding viewmodel.

ViewModel:

```
public class TreeViewViewModel : WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private List<TreeItemViewModel> _items;
    public List<TreeItemViewModel> Items { get { return _items; } set { _items = value; } }
    public RelayCommand<RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object>> SelectedItemChangedCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand<EventArgs> MouseDoubleClickCommand { get; private set; }

    public TreeViewViewModel()
    {
        SelectedItemChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object>>(e => OnSelectedItemChanged(e));
    }

    void OnSelectedItemChanged(RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        var xy = e;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="trvTemplate">
     <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand, Mode=OneWay}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>
```

I have read a few blogs and it should work but I get it not that a command is invoked. If there is a better or easier way to combine wpf treeview with mvvm pattern please give me the relevant info.

Comment: I just tried your sample and it fired the SelectedItemChanged without problem (I hardcoded the TreeViewItems). Did you already try to remove the unhandled `MouseLeftButtonDown` EventTrigger? Also remove the `Mode=OneWay` from your Command Binding.

Comment: I remove the MouseLeftButtonDown Trigger and remove the Mode=OneWay, but nothing happend. As I use a own ViewModel for each Treeview Item with implements INotifyPropertyChanged perhaps this will catch to SelectedItemChanged event before the treeview eventtrigger with the eventtocommand could be fired? I try it as you do and test it with hardcoded treeview items. Or any other ideas?

Comment: Can you include the `TreeViewItemViewModel` class? It's rather unusual to bind ViewModels - you'd normally bind an `ObservableCollection<T>` to your TreeView ItemsSource.